# How do I Setup Azure Functions TokenRequestContext Scopes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-identity

I am using a HttpClient to call an Azure Function App from an another Azure Function App, I am using a DelegatingHandler

And i can't remember how to activate the Scope api://{someGuid}/.default

However I have also realized I should be able to use

```
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] {"https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/.default"});
```

I need to be able to authenticate locally for testing and for when i upload function to function.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appriciated.

UPDATE:
I have done this article and although it returns the token, when i makes the request it comes back as unauthorised (testing locally)

https://awhnet.medium.com/securing-api-to-api-azure-app-services-using-managed-identity-ea02035c7d0d

Comment: sorted you can't call a AccessLevel.Function request locally